# What is this error? I am installing the Plots package of Julia language. I can't install just this package

Tags: julia

[image][Here is the issue that I am getting when trying to install the package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzgNU.jpg)

What is this error? I am  installing  the Plots package of Julia language?

Comment: Can you show the error? If you don’t edit this, it will likely be closed for not following the community guidelines so I suggest adding additional context ASAP so we can all help.

Comment: Also, please add some details about your environment. For example: are you behind a proxy or firewall?

Comment: Yeah, can you run the “st” command and edit the post above with the output?

Comment: I don't using proxy or firewall.

Comment: are you using the official binaries?

Comment: What is official binaries?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are running into https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/issues/1642. Perhaps you can try the fix suggested in https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/pull/1680#issuecomment-586769814.